# Turn Bluetooth on so it stays on even when trigger app is closed

Tags: tasker

Hi Guys I am trying to make a profile to turn on Bluetooth when I open Spotify. That works but as soon I switch the app to browse something while playing the music Tasker turns the Bluetooth off ;(.

So I want an Event when Spotify is opened turn on Bluetooth even if I delete Spotify it should stay on ;)

Does anyone know a solution?

Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an exit task that will turn on Bluetooth. And being that Bluetooth is already on, it will stay on till you manually switch it off.

To set an exit task, long press on the task and select "add exit task" there, select Bluetooth on as the task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively - you can specify that the profile should not restore settings:

1. Long-press on the profile
2. Tap 'gear' icon to access the profile's properties
3. Disable the 'Restore Settings' option